# Where to put file in Microsoft Visual Studio so that it will find them automatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've written a program at home on Linux and I have some files that are read in automatically. They are in the same directory as the `main.cpp` file and when I compile and run using
`g++ -Wall main.cpp && ./a.out`
the program finds the files, reads them in and works, using this function:

```
std::vector<std::string> returnFile(std::string filename) {
    std::ifstream infile;
    std::vector<std::string> contents;
    infile.open(filename.c_str());
    for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); ) {
        contents.push_back(line);
    }
    infile.close();
    return contents;
}
```

On Windows, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, where do I put the file so that I can run:
`returnFile("myFile.txt");`
and it will find the file?

Comment: If you run from the VS2010 IDE, it should go in the project folder. Otherwise in the same folder as the executable. Alternatively, you can put a path to the working directory in the project properties ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During normal compilation:
- the root directory is your Project direcoty.
(where your Project.vcxproj file is)

After Release:
- the root directory will be the one of your executeable.